# Kohana error for custom validation rule ReflectionException

Tags: php, validation, kohana

Very new to Kohana and I havnt developed in php for some time. Currently I am attempting to create some custom validation rules. With the OOTB validation rules the code works correctly, however when the two custom validation rules I recieve an error message.

```
ReflectionException [ 0 ]: Class Account_Model does not exist
```

All of the below code is found in a model called Account

```
public static function unique_username($username)
{
    //check to see if username existsin the database
    return ! DB::select(array(DB::expr('COUNT(username)'), 'total'))
        ->from('users')
        ->where('username', '=', $username)
        ->execute()
        ->get('total');
}


  public static function unique_email($email)
{
    // Check if the email already exists in the database
    return ! DB::select(array(DB::expr('COUNT(email)'), 'total'))
        ->from('users')
        ->where('email', '=', $email)
        ->execute()
        ->get('total');
}



 public function validate_new_user($post){

    $valid_post = Validation::factory($post);

         $valid_post->
                    ->rule('username', 'Account_Model::unique_username')
                    ->rule('email', 'Account_Model::unique_email'));
          if ($valid_post->check()) {
              return array('error' => false);
          } else {
              return array('error' => true, 'errors' => $valid_post->errors('default'));
          }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Account_Model` in your code needs to be `Model_Account`, that should also be the name of the class this is in.

```
$valid_post->//other rules
           ->rule('username', 'Model_Account::unique_username')
           ->rule('email', 'Model_Account::unique_email'));
```

Comment: ah I was close. Thanks for taking the time to look at that.